# Where can I see synced contacts

Tags: contacts, sync

I enabled contacts sync because I will have to factory reset my phone.
After cleaning up the mess joining accounts made, I would like to check if my phone contacts are indeed saved on Google servers so as to proceed to the wiping of memory.

Is there anyway to do this? contacts.google.com only shows Gmail contacts.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "enabled contacts sync"? Is this an app that came with your phone? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Ideally: you would input all of your contacts into Gmail/Google contacts, they will definitely be synced then

Comment: From the sync options for the Google account in Settings->Accounts. I had it off for Contacts. Having to manually input all my phonebook in Gmail won't do. I have a local file back does with Samsung Kies, but I'd rather keep them in the cloud.

Comment: That means they are going to be synced with your google account -- so you will see it with your Gmail contacts. That's where it syncs to/with, if you're talking about your address book / contacts app.

Comment: So, I'm syncing with my Google Account and I can't see them in GMail contacts or contacts.google.com which are the same page. Does that mean they aren't synced?

Comment: If they were synced, then you should be seeing them inside of Gmail

Comment: Maybe try some sort of backup app to csv and then import them in Google contacts on the web? For example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.uia.android.backupcontacts&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5vLnVpYS5hbmRyb2lkLmJhY2t1cGNvbnRhY3RzIl0. (I haven't tried this app, just a suggestion)

Comment: Yeah, but I was hoping it would just work, it's easy enough.